# conversion .xtend to .java

Tags: java, eclipse, xtend

I wanted to use the .xtend files which are implemented in other project.
For this purpose I need to convert that business logic from .xtend to .java source code.

Is there any way to convert .xtend file to java ? or do I need to implement it again in java.

Comment: Sure, Xtend is translated to Java source code, not to bytecode. You will need to install the [Xtend plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-xtend) for that.

Answer (score 1):

I found simplest way,
In eclipse

1. I have build the .xtend project (lets call it as **Project1**)and created jar.
2. I have included that Jar into other simple java project and attached the source to the jar class from **Project1** .
3. It will Automatically convert entire .xtend code into java code.

Thanks.